# Is there a way to merge two formulas in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a long list of unique formulas, with each one just referencing another cell in another workbook (i.e. ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1). The issue I am having is that I want to make sure that any blank cells in the other workbook evaluate to "" instead of 0, which is the default behavior.

I need to preserve the formatting of each of these cells, so I cannot simply use paste special to add "" to each cell (i.e. ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1+""), because this does not preserve formatting.

I tried using find and replace to add in the first part of an IF statement at the beginning, and then I would use the same methodology to put in the rest of IF Statement at the end, but Excel shows an error box when I try to do this (since the first step makes it an invalid formula) and doesn't do the replace, so I can't use this method.

The purpose of this question, is for me to see if there is a way I can put the formula ( =IF(A1="","",A1) ) into B1, where A1 contains the formula ( ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1 ), and then have some sort of setting make it so I could "merge" the formula, having AI evaluate to '[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1 and turn the formula into ( IF('[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1="","",'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1) )

If you have any other suggestions for accomplishing my task, please let me know.

Comment: While this is a little confusing, such as what `IF` statement you tried that didn't work, it seems you have your solution.  Are you trying to add another condition to your `IF` statement? And what prevents you from "merging" the formula and populating that instead of having a setting to change it?

Comment: My solution to my problem was using the formulatext() function. That way, I could use the methodology described in the third paragraph above, where I inserted "IF(" and the beginning and "="","",'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!$A$1)" at the end.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the need for the `FORMULATEXT` function in place of just putting the correct formula in the cells in the first place.  Also, you seem to have 2 questions here which is making it difficult to understand.  One is your blank cell evaluation and the other is the formula "merge".

Comment: The problem I was looking to solve is how I could turn the formula =A2 into =IF(A2="","",A2) for a list of hundreds of formulas of the form =A2. I can't rewrite each formula because that would take a very long time, so I needed a formulaic way of doing it. I thought the easiest way to do this would be merging formulas, as I thought that was something that existed in excel, so that's why I asked that question. Since asking it, though, I came up with another solution, posted in my previous comment.

Comment: Does the `'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'` change in your list?

Comment: try put `=IF('[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!A1="","",'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'!A1) ` in A1. Then copy and paste it all the way down + right.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I already solved it. The issue was that I had a list of formulas that were like ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$A$1, ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$B$42, ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$R$12, ='[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$A$4 and I had to put all of those ones into the form =IF(A2="","",A2) (ie for the first and second one: IF('[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$A$1="","",'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$A$1), IF('[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$B$42="","",'[Other_Workbook.xlsx]Sheet'$B$42) ), so I couldn't just rewrite the formulas and copy and paste down.